# Convert System::String to std::string in c++ simply?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I know that there are a lot of Google answers out there for this topic, but I keep getting an error in my code.

In a GUI using Visual Studio in C++, I declared a struct in Form1.h:

```
  struct char_build {
       string name; 
  } user;
```

But when I try to retrieve text from a Text Box like

```
 user.name = textBox1->Text;
```

There's an error with managed vs. unmanaged strings, and a String ^ isn't able to go into the struct.

Any ideas of the best way to retrieve input in the Text Box and use it in the struct? Thanks!

Comment: Can u please try String^ instead of string...

Comment: Thanks for the reference, chris, I'll check it out and close the question if that solves it for me. I've seen that answer before, but was curious if anyone knew of a simpler solution or if that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do this by first converting to a `wstring`, then to `string` using the iterator constructor:

```
wstring temp(textBox1->Text->Data());
user.name(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Comment: Let's not think too much about character sets and encoding, shall we :/